# How to share db connection like session across different users?

Tags: python, apache, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi

We're using Soaplib - Soap Server with apache/mod_wsgi and sqlalchemy as ORM for mysql connection.

We tried to use `global dict` to store the db session handled by sqlalchemy - `makesession` connection.

But when we move our code to the production environment using mod_wsgi it won't work, as it creates different processes for each request

So currently we've set `WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=1 threads=1` but it isn't a good solution.

What could be ideal solution to use global db connection pool to share db session across all requests?

Answer (score 0):

A new process is not created for each request. What you were likely doing is that you were running in embedded mode with Apache prefork MPM. Apache will create many processes to handle requests and your requests are likely being handled by the different processes in turn. Eventually the requests will come back and be handled by a process which has been used before and so hit the cached connection.

In general using embedded mode and prefork MPM is a bad idea. Use daemon mode and make you code thread safe and use a multithreaded process. If you don't understand how to make code thread safe, then use a small number of single thread daemon mode processes. Ie.,

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=4 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup example
```

This is still better than Apache prefork MPM and embedded mode because it is a fixed number where as in embedded mode the number can grow to be much larger and Apache can also kill off and restart processes. With daemon mode the processes will always be persistent with that configuration.

Comment: check the url http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/pages/usermanager.html we've followed this example for our project, is it thread safe ? currently `process=4 threads=1` is also not working...

Comment: At this point you are really going to have to expand in your original question what you mean by "won't work" and give the evidence for it as right now there is just not enough to go on. Also suggest you turn on 'LogLevel info' in Apache as it will give more detailed information about what mod_wsgi is doing and also confirm you haven't stuffed up with embedded mode still being used.

Comment: won't work = can't share the variable globally,  each process is having its own copy of global variables. what is embedded mode in apachy, how can I use, any specific help/url may help me out.  Thanks !

Comment: I think the problem may be your understanding of what a global variable is then. A global variable is still local to the process it is in. It is not shared across processes, that isn't how process memory management works. For some background about data sharing read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading and then perhaps go read up on some basic material on process management in operating systems and memory management.